# Playchess client for Mac

Tags: software, macos

Is it possible that world's most famous and most popular chess server **Playchess** is not available in any desktop application for `Mac OSX`? It is possible to reach it through `Deep Fritz` for `Windows`, but what about the `Mac` users? I know there is a [web-client](http://play.chessbase.com/js/apps/playchess/), but frankly, it soo suxx it hurts to even see it, let alone try and use it. Also, I have tried e-mailing them at [support@playchess.com](http://support@playchess.com) regarding this issue, but the e-mail is broken! They can't even receive an e-mail. So much from a customer support. Is anyone else confronted with this problem, and what is the right way to fight it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, yes. There were times I installed Windows just because of playchess.com doesn't support other operation systems. Your options are:

1. Installing Windows

   - with *boot camp*
   - in a *virtual machine*
2. Installing a compability layer

   - *Wine* (free)
   - *Crossover* (commercial)

**Helpful links**

- http://www.howtogeek.com/187359/5-ways-to-run-windows-software-on-a-mac/
- http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/

Answer (score 0):

It's annoying, Chessbase abandoned the Mac sometime ago.

However their web based client works reasonably well as long as you're not playing bullet games:

http://play.chessbase.com/js/apps/playchess/

I'm guessing they're hedging their bets on migrating to web based services so I doubt we'll ever see a Mac client.

The other alternative is using the Windows client through something like Parallels.